# Point cloud using pcl visualizer

Tags: metrics, ply, pcl

I have a pointcloud data which is a ply file. Using pcl library I tried visualising the data. But when trying to do a click event I'm getting the coordinates(435,234). My doubt is what will be unit of (435,234) as I'm trying to do a click event on the screen using pcl.

I have a doubt if it can be a pixel coordinates.Since it is a ply file visualisation using pcl, I want to know the unit or metric behind it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <pcl/filters/statistical_outlier_removal.h>
#include <Eigen/Core> 
#include <cmath> 


pcl::PointXYZRGB clicked_points[2];
int num_clicked = 0;

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

void mouseEventOccurred(const pcl::visualization::MouseEvent& event, void* viewer_void)
{
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer* viewer = static_cast<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer*>(viewer_void);
    if (event.getButton() == pcl::visualization::MouseEvent::LeftButton && event.getType() == pcl::visualization::MouseEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        clicked_points[num_clicked % 2].x = event.getX();
        clicked_points[num_clicked % 2].y = event.getY();
        std::cout << "point_clicked->(" << clicked_points[num_clicked % 2].x << "," << clicked_points[num_clicked % 2].y << ")" << std::endl;
        num_clicked++;

        if (num_clicked % 2 == 0)//calculate distance for every pair of two clicked points
        {
            double distance = std::sqrt(std::pow(clicked_points[1].x - clicked_points[0].x, 2) + std::pow(clicked_points[1].y - clicked_points[0].y, 2));
            std::cout << "Distance between clicked points->" << distance << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    pcl::console::setVerbosityLevel(pcl::console::L_ERROR);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::io::loadPLYFile("humanoid.ply", *cloud);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Point_Cloud");
    viewer.setBackgroundColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(cloud_filtered, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(cloud_filtered),"filtered_cloud");
    viewer.registerMouseCallback(mouseEventOccurred, (void*)&viewer);

    while (!viewer.wasStopped()) {
        viewer.spinOnce(100, true);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code. Here I have to perform distance so when trying to find it by using click event I have a doubt in metric as the clicked coordinate is 2D.

Also in my case I have to find distance of a curved surface of a given object So is there  a way to map the 2d point I click on screen with the original 3D data of the clicked part.

Comment: How do you make the click? Do you use the PointPickingEvent? Show us some code. The metric is not given. If your source data is in meters, then it's meters. If it is millilmeter then it is millimeter.